# Compiling Oracle package from Client machine using SQL PLUS

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, package

While Compiling Oracle package from the Client machine using SQL PLUS it gave error

```
ORA-03135: Connection Lost
Process Id :###
Session ID : ### Serial No :###
```

Comment: I guess you tried it more than once, right? Is the database server up and running? Can you, for example, successfully run a SELECT statement right after you got that message during package compilation? Does someone hold the package (because it is in use), which prevents you from compiling it? Does this error happen *always*, or just *today*?

Comment: Does this only happen for compiling one particular package, or for compiling anything, or for any command at all? Perhaps something on this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21881587/230471

Comment: If the package contents are too much sometimes it gives this error and there is no issue with connectivity, the select statement is executing..

Comment: @Littlefoot No one is using the package we are compiling the same on the development server hence there is no possibility of holding the same package by another process