# NodeJS oracledb - ORA-03135: connection lost contact

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I have a NodeJS application which uses oracledb library to connect to an Oracle Database . It's using the following code to try to connect to the database:

```
        this.oracledb.fetchAsBuffer = [this.oracledb.BLOB];
        const dbconfig = {
            user: 'mysuser',
            password: 'mypass',
            connectString: '10.xxx.xx.xxx/MYORCLID'
        };
        console.log("Trying to get connection");
        return await this.oracledb.getConnection(dbconfig);
```

But, I'm receiving the following error now during the "getConnection" method:

```
"Error: ORA-03135: connection lost contact"
```

Please, is there anything wrong with this code? It was working before but suddenly I started to receive the above message. From where should I start to check?

I've tried `telnet` and it worked too, so I'm not sure if this is a firewall issue.

Comment: maybe this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163370/ora-03135-connection-lost-contact-when-inserting-large-file#:~:text=The%20ORA%2D03135%20error%20is,in%20a%20SQL*Plus%20profile.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue.

It was an internal blocking issue inside our network. They use a type of application which checks the origin hostname, linux user, application name and other properties before allowing access to the database.

After talking to my Infra and DB Team, they checked and liberated the access, and then everything worked as it should.

Thanks!